# NSFetchedResultsController not processing certain section driven moves

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I utilize a NSFetchedResultsController (frc) with a Core Data store. I implement all the frc delegate methods. The table is sporadically updated by background threads. All the inserts, deletes and updates work fine, with the exception that updates to the frc's index key for rows toward to the bottom of the table (50 rows), do not result in a section move. e.g. if "name" is the index key and the name "Victor" is changed to "Alex", the victor row now shows the name Alex, but is not moved to the top of the table alongside all other names starting with A. As I noted, this is only for rows towards the bottom of the table. If a row like "Andy" is changed to "Ben", the move is indeed processed correctly by the frc. Any suggestions to fix this would be appreciated. I do not use a frc cache. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few twitchy issues with the FRC and table view sections in pre-4.0 Core Data.  I would suggest retesting in 4.0; if it works and you need to be 3.x compliant then do table reloads instead for 3.x to avoid some of the refresh issues.

### update

If the issue is persisting in 4.0, then I **highly** recommend building a test case to duplicate the issue. This will accomplish several things:

- it will give me a clearer picture of the issue.
- it may show you the solution.
- if we are both stumped you can submit it to Apple so they can fix the API

I cannot suggest this strongly enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, these issues persist in 4.0. My workaround is in fact a reload as you suggested. I hope all the frc issues will be resolved eventually.